# How to increase value of dynamic variable by 1 in the for loop?

Tags: jquery

Here is my example

```
for(var z = 1; z <= 26; z++){
    value[z] = $('#DiskSize'+z).val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
}
```

So how to get these results:

```
value[1] = $('#DiskSize1').val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
value[2] = $('#DiskSize2').val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
....
value[26] = $('#DiskSize26').val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
```

I'm trying to convert z to string (`var value = $('#DiskSize'+z.toString()).val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');`) but still nothing!

Could anyone help me please!

Comment: Your example should work.... what's not working?

Comment: try adding this to see what you're getting?  `console.log('#DiskSize'+z);`... it should work.

Comment: This part is fine: `value[z] = $('#DiskSize'+z).val()`. If you are not seeing correct results then either you don't have the correct ID values in your html, or your replace logic is wrong... or you have errors - check the console!

Comment: why $('#DiskSize'+z.toString()) why not just $('#DiskSize'+z)

Comment: `replace` returns things by value, btw.  it's not a by reference function.  `var modified_string = init_string.replace('x','y');` therefore, `init_string` never changes.

Comment: maybe its a problem that you are beginning to fill the array at the second index, i.e. 1, not 0

Comment: concentanating a string and a number will end up as a string, and jQuery has a trim function built in -> `value[z] = $.trim( $('#DiskSize'+z).val() );`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/23geV/

Comment: Do you have some HTML to go with your example?

Comment: @Alex - the loop does start at 1 but your idea might be correct in the inverse of that

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I using IE8 and I noticed that its working in Opera but not in Firefox and IE8!!! Why????????

Comment: Before the code `for(var z = 1; z <= 26; z++){` are you declaring `var value = [];` or `var value = new Array();`? Javascript can be very fussy if you don't declare a variable as an array before trying to set indexes for it.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a shot in the dark since you did not show your HTML in the question. It's also not clear what results you are getting.*

The [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function can be used to get the value of `<input>` elements and other form field elements. But if you want the text inside an element (like a `<div>`, `<span>` or `<p>` element), you should use the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.